# Laravel : Fetching records with condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, logic

I have four models `User`,`Reward`,`RewardUnlocked`,`RewardClaimed` And the relationship between them is :

`User` have many `RewardUnlocked`,=>(Many to one)

`User` have many `RewardClaimed`=>(Many to one)

`Reward` have many `RewardUnlocked`=>(Many to one)

`Reward` have many `RewardClaimed`=>(Many to one)

The introduction of the problem is that a user will first unlock a reward when a specific condition becomes true,

**Now the issue is that i want to fetch all the rewards from `Reward` table and show to the user, And check each reward that if the `reward_id` is present in `RewardUnlocked` then show a `check sign` if not present then show `cross sign`**

The view file is a `header` file so i am sending the variable via ajax.

For the time being my code is

controller :

```
$rewards = App\Reward::all();
  foreach ($rewards as $reward){
    $list = App\User::with('unlocks')->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
  }
```

**The problem with the following code is that i have to send the reward list , And show there with a check sign or cross sign that you have unlocked the reward.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be more clear, I understand that you need to show a list of reward in the user profile, with whatever rewards unlocked, a check sign respectively and rest a cross sign, 
if its the case, then you can use belongs to many relation with your user table to rewards table, and a status column to track reward claimed and reward unlocked and you can access it as pivot attribute, so whatever reward not in the middle table are not unlocked, 
you may read on the Laravel doc about Many to Many relation to understand further https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many